NodeJS is re-instantiating variables multiple times
I have a Node.js application with the following code structure:
SqlUtils.js
const queryMap = new Map([
  // various query mappings => size over 20KB
]);

function generateSQLQuery(select) {
  const clauses = new Set();

  Object.keys(select).forEach((key) => {
    if (queryMap.has(key) && select[key]) {
      clauses.add(queryMap.get(key));
    }
  });
  return Array.from(clauses).join(",\n");
}

module.exports = {
  generateSQLQuery
};


The function generateSQLQuery is imported in a separate service using require, this service is used on almost every request.
I've noticed that when handling multiple requests (e.g., over 400 requests/s), the memory usage can be quite high. By moving queryMap to a separate module and importit using Node.js module caching, I observed a significant reduction in memory consumption—over 200MB saved.
My questions are:

Does Node.js instantiate queryMap multiple times if generateSQLQuery is called concurrently without module caching?

Are there any best practices for optimizing memory usage with large constant data structures in a Node.js application besides moving them to separate module?


Any insights or detailed explanations would be greatly appreciated.
NodeJS runtime 18.12.0
I solved the problem but I would like to understand why it was happening.
